# Mongoose: deleting null value in the array?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have an array like below for multiple documents.

```
meta: [1, null]
```

I want to get rid of the `null` value. So the array just looks like

```
meta: [1]
```

I tried with `$unset`

```
.updateMany({}, { $unset: { 'meta.1': 1 } }, { multi: true });
```

However, it doesn't remove `null` value. How can I keep the value `1` but just take off `null` from the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) to remove element from array, and `updateMany()` not require `multi: true` option,

```
.updateMany(
  { meta: null }, 
  { $pull: { meta: null } }
)
```